# La compilación con VS Code muestra mal las Ñs y los caracteres con tilde

Tags: java, windows, vscode, compilar, idioma

Estoy empezando a utilizar **VS Code** (a la vez que me estoy iniciando en la programación) con Java.
En las aplicaciones que voy desarrollando uso como encoding **UTF-8** o ISO 8859-1 (europa occidental). Al ejecutarlas desde VS Code los caracteres como la **Ñ o las tildes** aparecen mal representados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando compilo el mismo código directamente con **javac** o lo ejecuto desde **IntelliJ** dichos caracteres aparecen perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado mirando documentación y trasteando la configuración de VS Code y no he encontrado nada que me lo solucione. El último cambio ha sido en la detección de idioma local pero tampoco funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo un equipo con Windows 8. ¿Alguien me puede indicar como hacer esto? Gracias.

Comment: Supongo estás en window, normalmente en linux no ocurre ese problema. Prueba ejecutando en la terminal integrada de vscode el comando `chcp 65001`. Al parecer a alguien le funcionó en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612504/how-to-correctly-display-unicode-characters-in-vs-codes-integrated-terminal)

Comment: Creo que es más un problema de compilación que de terminal. El código compilado en VS Code también tiene problemas si lo ejecuto en el cmd de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

En VS Code Integrated Terminal, escriba el comando: `chcp 65001` Entonces debería mostrar Unicode correctamente.

Comment: Gracias, Agustín. He probado lo que me dices y no funciona. El código `System.out.println("¿Dónde está León? En España");` da como salida: ï¿½Dï¿½nde estï¿½ Leï¿½n? En Espaï¿½a